# Is this Rule a sufficient protection from that security hole?

Tags: php, security, apache, mod-rewrite

I had a problem where a file on a webserver was locally edited with a command line editor.

The editor created a backup file suffixed with the `~` character.

So there was a file named `file.php~`

This file could be directly downloaded over the webserver, because it was not processed as a php file.

I thought about a directive like this:

```
<Files ~ "~$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

so every file that ends with  `~` is denied for delivery.

Is this a good method, did I miss something?

Comment: what is to stop them from changing ~ to some other character?

Comment: Better solution is to tell the editor to NOT create the backup file, and/or simply edit the file somewhere outside of your document root.

Comment: Why don't you just allow only .php files to be executed and only .css/.png/.js.... etc. files be read instead of just avoiding this one case? I think it is a good thing to do even if you didn't have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should adequately solve it; however, the bigger problem is in editing directly on the server, when you should be using source control (such svn, git) and then deploying from the source control.  What if another editor uses `.bak` ?

Comment: i totally agree on this one. however it is hard to gain control over human error ;) in this case it was an unversioned file (local config including database access data). credentials were changed which was the reason for editing it locally in the first place.

Comment: credential files really shouldn't even be in the web root, but I realize that many, many php apps out there do it.